# VueJS can't render this text

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have this specific string in my db:

`s"""{{{}}>>> ;d's`

And as many other projects, my application root is the `#app` which wraps all my application.

When I try to display that string on screen

as this (blade template):

```
<div class="content">
    {{ $project->description }}
</div>
```

I got

```
invalid expression: Unexpected token ')' in

    "s&quot;&quot;&quot;"+_s({)+"&gt;&gt;&gt; ;d&#039;s"

  Raw expression: s&quot;&quot;&quot;{{{}}&gt;&gt;&gt; ;d&#039;s
```

error from Vue on console. I'm using a laravel application and blade templates. What should I do to show the string as is?

Comment: You can try unescaping the string by doing this: `{!! $project->description !!}`, but use this only if you 100% trust the content that will be rendered otherwise you may be vulnerable to XSS attacks

Comment: The same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the text being interpreted as Vue template syntax by using `v-pre`:

```html
<div v-pre class="content">
    {{ $project->description }}
</div>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-pre